# Faster AUC in sklearn or python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, auc

I have over half a million pairs of true labels and predicted scores (the length of each 1d array varies and can be between 10,000-30,000 in length) that I need to calculate the AUC for. Right now, I have a for-loop that calls:

```
# Simple Example with two pairs of true/predicted values instead of 500,000
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np

pred = [None] * 2
pred[0] = np.array([3,2,1])
pred[1] = np.array([15,12,14,11,13])

true = [None] * 2
true[0] = np.array([1,0,0])
true[1] = np.array([1,1,1,0,0])

for i in range(2):
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(true[i], pred[i])
    print metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
```

However, it takes about 1-1.5 hours to process the entire dataset and calculate the AUC for each true/prediction pair. Is there a faster/better way to do this?

**Update**

Each of the 500k entries can have shape (1, 10k+). I understand that I could parallelize it but I'm stuck on a machine with only two processors and so my time can really only be effectively cut down to say, 30-45, minutes which is still too long. I've identified that the AUC calculation itself is slow and was hoping to find a faster AUC algorithm than what is available in sklearn. Or, at least, find a better way to vectorize the AUC calculation so that it can be broadcasted across multiple rows.

Comment: so to be clear, your `pred` and `true` arrays have length 500k entries, each of which is an np.array with shape (10k, 1)? if yes, you want to calculate the auc for each of pred[i|/true[i] combinations, that is each calculation is independent?

Comment: how much time does the AUC calculation for one pair take? How much time `t` per each pair would be allowable in order to get down to what you need (i.e. `t * 0.5e6 < T_max`? I'm assuming you have already looked at the cost/benefit ratio of spending time to optimize this v.s. the cost to buy a larger machine (or rent one e.g. at AWS for the time of the calculation).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a faster/better way to do this?

Since the calculation of each true/pred pair is independent (if I understood your setup), you should be able to reduce total processing time by using [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), effectively parallelizing the calculations:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def roc(v):
    """ calculate one pair, return (index, auc) """
    i, true, pred = v
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(true, pred, drop_intermediate=True)
    auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
    return i, auc

pool = mp.Pool(3) 
result = pool.map_async(roc, ((i, true[i], pred[i]) for i in range(2)))
pool.close()
pool.join()
print result.get()
=>
[(0, 1.0), (1, 0.83333333333333326)]
```

Here `Pool(3)` creates a pool of 3 processes, `.map_async` maps all true/pred pairs and calls the `roc` function, passing one pair at a time. The index is sent along to map back results.

If the true/pred pairs are too large to serialize and send to the processes, you might need to write the data into some external data structure before calling `roc`, passing it just the reference `i` and read the data for each pair `true[i]/pred[i]` from within `roc` before processing.

A [Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) automatically manages the scheduling of processes. To reduce the risk of a memory hog, you might need to pass the `Pool(...., maxtasksperchild=1)` parameter which would start a new process for each true/pred pair (choose any other number as you see fit).

**Update**

> I'm stuck on a machine with only two processors

naturally this is a limiting factor. However considering the availability of cloud computing resources at very reasonable cost that you only pay for the time you actually need it, you might want to consider alternatives in hardware before you spend eons of hours optimizing a calculation that can be so effectively parallelized. That's a luxury in its own right, really.

Answer (score 1):

> find a better way to vectorize the AUC calculation so that it can be broadcasted across multiple rows

Probably not - sklearn already uses efficient numpy operations for its calculation of relevant parts:

```
# -- calculate tps, fps, thresholds
# sklearn.metrics.ranking:_binary_clf_curve()
(...)
distinct_value_indices = np.where(np.logical_not(isclose(
        np.diff(y_score), 0)))[0]
threshold_idxs = np.r_[distinct_value_indices, y_true.size - 1]
# accumulate the true positives with decreasing threshold
tps = (y_true * weight).cumsum()[threshold_idxs]
if sample_weight is not None:
    fps = weight.cumsum()[threshold_idxs] - tps
else:
    fps = 1 + threshold_idxs - tps
return fps, tps, y_score[threshold_idxs]

# -- calculate auc
# sklearn.metrics.ranking:auc()
...
area = direction * np.trapz(y, x)
...
```

You might be able to optimize this by profiling these functions and removing operations that you can apply more efficiently beforehand. A quick profiling of your example input scaled to 5M rows reveals a few potential bottlenecks (marked `>>>`):

```
# your for ... loop wrapped in function roc()
%prun -s cumulative roc
722 function calls (718 primitive calls) in 5.005 seconds
Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.005    5.005 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.005    5.005 <ipython-input-51-27e30c04d997>:1(roc)
        2    0.050    0.025    5.004    2.502 ranking.py:417(roc_curve)
        2    0.694    0.347    4.954    2.477 ranking.py:256(_binary_clf_curve)
     >>>2    0.000    0.000    2.356    1.178 fromnumeric.py:823(argsort)
     >>>2    2.356    1.178    2.356    1.178 {method 'argsort' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        6    0.062    0.010    0.961    0.160 arraysetops.py:96(unique)
     >>>6    0.750    0.125    0.750    0.125 {method 'sort' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
     >>>2    0.181    0.090    0.570    0.285 numeric.py:2281(isclose)
        2    0.244    0.122    0.386    0.193 numeric.py:2340(within_tol)
        2    0.214    0.107    0.214    0.107 {method 'cumsum' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I stumbled upon this problem myself and created a number of methods that are way faster than the standard sklearn realization. You can choose either of them depending on which suits you the most.

Python based is approximately **8X faster** than the default sklearn

Python+numba based is approximately **26X faster** than the default sklearn

C++/ctypes based is approximately **37X faster** than the default sklearn

The code is here: https://github.com/diditforlulz273/fastauc

10k simple AUC calculations run time with sklearn included:

[10k simple AUC calculations run time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHkhY.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33443853)

Comment: Great, Vsevolod, I can confirm your numbers on a 8M records dataset. Now need to find classification_report implementation of the same performance )

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a vectorized way to calculate ROC AUC. It's faster than sklearns implementation. Suppose you have N examples with N_pos (+1) and N_neg (-1).

So N = N_pos + N_neg

Compute an index vector (I): [1, 2, 3, 4,..., N]

Compute the ranking vector (R): [1, 0, 1, ..., 1]

The ranking vector is where your 0s and 1s end up due to your ranking score (e.g., predicted probability from model). The first position means this label got the highest score.

Now we have vectorized way to compute ROC AUC:

[image: Vectorized form of ROC AUC]

See here for details and a comparison to sklearn: https://medium.com/building-ibotta/understanding-roc-auc-part-2-2-a1e418a3afdb